# How can I integrate front page files from online softwares to my own website file system?

Tags: node.js, frontend, filesystems, integration-testing

I have a problem with building the front page of my website. I need to build the front page without any daunting, time-consuming coding.

I have tried using some free online softwares that can help me design front end pages. However, when I attempted downloading the files (HTML, CSS, JS) using inspect element, I've realised that the file system was wayy too complicated for me to integrate into my web files system.

Here is what I have attempted.
[image]
[image]